# How do I clone/copy a model instance and preserve its associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Right now I have the following, which works fine:

```
  e                    = Event.find(params[:based_on_id])
  @event               = e.clone
  @event.tag_ids       = e.tag_ids
  @event.subcategories = e.subcategories
```

However I would like to avoid the last two lines, especially since my model may change its association structure in the future. I just want a pristine "new" copy, which includes all associations.

Note: the associations above are has_many :through.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in an overriden Event.clone method